# Ruby on Rails Splitting or Slicing list into columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
@locations = Location.all #current listing all

@locations = Location.slice(5) or Location.split(5)
```

With Ruby I'm trying to split my list into 4 columns, limiting each column to 5 each; however neither slicing or splitting seems to work. Any idea of what I might be doing wrong? any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably want to use in_groups_of:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/28-in-groups-of

Here's Ryan Bates' example usage from that railscast:

```
<table>
<% @tasks.in_groups_of(4, false) do |row_tasks| %>
  <tr>
    <% for task in row_tasks %>
      <td><%= task.name %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Would something like the following suit your purposes?

```
Location.find_in_batches(batch_size: 5) do |group|
  # code to work with these 5 elements
end
```

> [find_in_batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches) yields each batch of records that was found by
>   the find options as an array.

Comment: This works, but `in_groups_of` is probably more appropriate for this task. From the API (you link to): This method is only intended to use for batch processing of large amounts of records that wouldn’t fit in memory all at once. If you just need to loop over less than 1000 records, it’s probably better just to use the regular find methods.